# Vite build commnad fails with ssr.noExternal

Tags: build, vite, svelte

I am trying to build svelte project with vite and I'm facing the issue, that when I import an external library into the project it throws the following error:

> [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".css"

I've found a solution for that problem by adding the following line to the `vite.config.ts`:

```
{
   ssr: {
      noExternal: **regexp here**
   }
}
```

It worked indeed, but when I try to build the project with `vite build` it fails with the following error:

> FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

What might be the problem?

Basically, I just don't know what goes wrong, because I've tried to build this project on my PC and it worked, buy when I try to build it on my laptop or using GH Actions it fails :(